# Is it possible for a wizard to add a non-wizard spell to their spellbook in D&D Beyond?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, wizard, dnd-beyond

There are several magic items that allow a wizard to add non-wizard spells to their spellbook, such as the [*Astromancy Archive*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/astromancy-archive):

> When found, it contains the following spells, which are wizard spells for you while you are attuned to it: *augury*, *divination*, *find the path*, *foresight*, *locate creature*, and *locate object*. It functions as a spellbook for you, with spells encoded on the rings.

Since it functions as a spellbook, per description, it means that a wizard can prepare one (or more) of the listed spells after a long rest.

The problem is that some of those spells are not on the Wizard spell list by default (*e.g.*, [*Divination*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/divination)): when one searches one of these spell for adding it in the spellbook (under the subpanel *Add Spell* of the *Manage Spell* panel), they do not appear, obviously.

Is there any way for a wizard to add a non-wizard spell to their spellbook in D&D Beyond?

Comment: I have discovered a truly marvelous solution to this problem, which this site is too narrow to contain.. I mean, I may have found a workaround for solving this, but I would like to ask to the collective wisdom of RPG.SE if a more elegant one can be found!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Use the spell as a template for a homebrew spell and add Wizard to the available classes.

Navigate to the create a homebrew spell page:

[image]

Use the desired spell as a template for a new homebrew spell:

[image]

When making a copy of a spell I like to give it a parenthetical note about why I’m making a copy:

[image]

Next, add the desired classes to the “available for” section:

[image]

And finally, to prevent the copy from showing up on other classes, delete all but Wizard:

[image]

Save changes, and the spell should appear in your spell list if your campaign has homebrew turned on:

[image]

This is an easy enough way to do it, it took around two minutes to create this spell and write this answer on my iPhone. You might be in for a lot of work if you’re adding a lot of spells, but I could set up the five spells mentioned in the question in less than 10 minutes from my phone, and it would be much faster on desktop.

#### Homebrew a copy of your subclass.

There is another way to do this, which is to make a homebrew subclass, using your chosen subclass as a template. This method has one notable limitation: *it only works with content you actually own, not with content that is shared with you*.

If you do own the subclass you are using, you can create a copy of it in the homebrew tool, and there is a section for adding individual spells:

[image]

Then it will show up in your arcane traditions section of the class select screen:

[image]

And now all of the spells will appear in your spell list on the character sheet. If you add spells that are already Wizard spells, they will show up twice:

[image]

Now, I am not sure how changing subclasses would affect other choices you have made, so I would recommend making a copy of your character and experimenting with that one first before making any changes to your live character sheet.

Comment: And that's the marvelous solution I have found... I hoped that some better options were possible, or that there were some hidden features of the item that I missed..

Comment: @Eddymage Added a second method.

Comment: I think that homebrewing the subclass is quite delicate: the first way looks more safe for me. I really wonder why dndbeyond did not manage to handle this kind of magic items, it is been a while that they are out

Comment: @Eddymage: I think that for most such cases of DDB not managing to handle game features, it's because the system wasn't originally designed with such possibilities in mind (because they didn't exist in the game at the time DDB created those systems). DDB's content entry system basically uses the same framework as the homebrew creator; this works fine as a workaround, but it wouldn't be the right way to implement it officially, so DDB needs to make changes to those underlying systems before this sort of item can officially work as intended.